# How do I make an optional binding in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Here is my client:

```
class Client {
    @Inject(optional=true) Service service;
}
```

Sometimes that Service isn't needed, and we know that information when the JVM starts (i.e before the binder is run).
How do I make the binding optional? If I don't specify a binding at all it tries to new the Service (and fails because there is no zero-argument constructor: "*Error while injecting at package.Client.service(Service.java:40): Could not find a suitable constructor in package.Service.*"), and I can't do:

```
binder.bind(Service.class).toInstance(null);
```

because Guice seems to disallow nulls. Any ideas?

Comment: guice suggest to use `binder.bind(Service.class).toProvider(Providers.<Service>of(null));`

Comment: Folks coming across this question may be interested in Guice's [`OptionalBinding`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/OptionalBinder.html) class, which allows you to provide a binding that may-or-may-not be set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using Guice 2.0? I've tried this both with `Service` being an interface (service field is always `null`) and with it being a class (`null` if it can't create a new instance with a JIT binding, an instance if it can). Both seem like what you'd expect.

In neither case did I use a binding like `bind(Service.class).toInstance(null)`. If you do this, then you need to make sure that all injection points for `Service` specify that they allow it to be `null`. This can be done by annotating the injection point with any annotation called `@Nullable` (you can make your own or use an existing one):

```
class Client {
    @Inject @Nullable Service service;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the existence of a binding optional you can use `@Inject(optional = true)` for field and method injections. For contructor and other parameter type injections, you must use a helper class, for example:

```
class Foo {
  public String hello(Helper helper) {
    return Helper.string;
  }
  private static final class Helper {
    @Inject(optional = true) public String string = "";
  }
}
```

Note that the above doesn't allow `null` to be injected, so Foo#hello will never return `null`. If you do want to allow `null`, simply add the `@Nullable` annotation. Keep in mind that code like the following will fail unless you've provided a binding (to null, if nothing else) for String:

```
class Bar {
  @Inject @Nullable public String hello(@Nullable String string) {
    return string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce this behavior. When I run this example code, the injector creates and the optional injection is left unsatisfied. The program prints `null`:

```
public class OptionalInjections {

  static class Service {
    public Service(Void v) {} // not injectable
  }

  static class Client {
    @Inject(optional = true) Service service;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector i = Guice.createInjector();
    Client client = i.getInstance(Client.class);
    System.out.println(client.service);
  }
}
```

Could you reproduce this in a JUnit test case and submit it to the [Guice issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/list)?

Comment: Running your test I get:

com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Error at Scratch$Service.<init>(Scratch.java:15) Error while injecting at Scratch$Client.service(Scratch.java:18): Could not find a suitable constructor in Scratch$Service. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor.

However, I've realised I'm using Guice 1.0 - it isn't something I've ever thought to upgrade. Now on Guice 2.0 and I get null as one might expect. Thanks!